# How to get scss files from bootstrap that will support me only navbar menu and not entire bootstrap lib?

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a problem when I download scss files from bootstrap, I have too many @import that I don't need I only need @import nav and navbar but there is a lot of errors that happen. Is there any generator of bootstrap code or any other way to help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say why you're getting so many errors without seeing your code, but in general if you only want the styles of `nav` and `navbar`, you can just import like this:

```
// custom.scss
// Required
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
```

Assuming your project structure is:

```
WebProject
- Assets
  - css
    - custom.scss
- node_modules
  - bootstrap
```

Comment: I need to add that this works only if you are doing inside bootstrap.scss folder and not outside  in custom class and the order is very important!   Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Neo: Nope, it doesn't make sense to modify existing `bootstrap.scss` because when there is a newer version of bootstrap available and you use Nuget or npm to get the latest, it will override what you've already done. For my example up there I am doing it inside the `custom.scss`! That's the whole point of creating a separate file (called custom.scss) to reference bootstrap and re-compile it into your own theme, instead of just referencing bootstrap.css.